# how to show order id no on checkout success page opencart 3.x

Tags: opencart-3

i have add following code at following mentions file but order id no not show just show Order ID  and after Order ID  Order number no mention 
i am using opencart 3.x

edit the success.php file in  catalog\controller\checkout\

Change this:

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
 $this->cart->clear();
```

Into this:

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
 $this->load->model('checkout/order');
 $data['orderDetails'] = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
 $this->cart->clear();
```

edit success.twig in catalog\view\theme\YOUR-THEME\template\common\

Under the line

I added the following:

```
 <?php if(!empty($orderDetails['order_id'])): ?>
 <h2>OrderID=<?php echo $orderDetails['order_id']; ?></h2>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to show order ID or invoice number?

Comment: order id at success page of checkout

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary load model and get order table to obtain order_id if session not cleared and order_id is not unset... just use this:

```
 $data['orderDetails'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

And next...  twig files not "understand" php like this:

```
<?php if(!empty($orderDetails['order_id'])): ?>
 <h2>OrderID=<?php echo $orderDetails['order_id']; ?></h2>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

try cahnge to:

```
{% if (orderDetails.order_id is not empty) %}
 <h2>OrderID={{ orderDetails.order_id }}</h2>
 {% endif %}
```